# how to use a list of objects as query in graphene?

Tags: python-3.x, graphene-python

I have a list of objects that I got from a third-party api:

```
heroes : [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "James"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Monk"
    }
]
```

This is where I think I'm stumped I can create a dictionary to load one data but what if I have multiple objects?

```
def get_hero(heroes):
   hero = {}
   hero['hero_id'] = heroes[0]['id']
   hero['hero_name'] = heroes[0]['name']
   return hero
```

Graphene related:

```
   class Hero(ObjectType):
       hero_id = Int()
       hero_name = String()

   
   class Query(ObjectType):
       hero_search = Field(Hero, hero_id=String())

       def resolve_hero_search(self, info, **kwargs):
          return get_hero(heroes=kwargs) # this is a just a placeholder cause I think there is no issue here
```

Query in graphene works okay but if only one data is included but I'm not sure if there are multiple objects.

Comment: It is not clear what you exactly wish to do? Could you explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a list of ID/Strings from input:

```
hero_search = Field(Hero, hero_id=graphene.List(graphene.String))
```